# EBImage - Fluorescence Microscopy image analysis (2-NBD-glucose uptake in adipocytes)

Tags: image-processing

I am struggling with Bioconductor's EBImage to develop a pipeline to analyse fluorescence microscopy images recorded in 96-well-plates with about 600 adipocytes per picture. The experiment compares WT and experimental condition with regard to fluorescent 2-NBDG glucose uptake.
I have two images per well: the GFP-channel (to record fluorescence), and the Hoechst-stained (to stain all nuclei for cell counting).
Is anyone aware of or has anyone previously used EBImage for this kind of analysis? I want to define in each image the cells and their outline, want to measure the fluorescence intensity for all cells, and normalise by the number of cells per image. 
I currently use ImageJ - but there is so much arbitrariness in manually adjusting thresholds etc. that it would be good and scientifically proper to have a scrutinisable R script for standard image analysis.
Any help on accomplishing this in R (maybe EBImage is not the best package)?

Thanks ever so much!
Best,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to stick with R then **EBImage** is probably your best bet. Have a look at the [package vignette](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/EBImage/inst/doc/EBImage-introduction.html) and at the [BioC2015 slides](https://bioconductor.org/help/course-materials/2015/BioC2015/BioC2015Oles.html) for a general overview of the functionality offered by the package. For a more specific application to cellular phenotypes see, e.g. the *Image segmentation and feature extraction* section of the [HD2013SGI vignette](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/data/experiment/vignettes/HD2013SGI/inst/doc/HD2013SGI.pdf).